# js multiple hover boxes with response in same box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a page with 35+ small grey boxes offering different subjects. when you hover over them i would like a short description of each subject to appear in a single larger yellow box.

i've shrunk the html to just two boxes and have a http://jsfiddle.net/x4q381L5/

my goal is for the one yellow box to be visible on the page with holding text. when you hover over the grey 'excel tips' box, the yellow box will display 'tips'. when you hover over 'aps' the same yellow box will display 'access' and so on for 35+ boxes.

i can see i am calling another 'toolkithelpbox' each time but in my brain i would need to create 35 different classes or ids to make this work and perhaps there is a better way.

(nb in the css i did have the cell as a span of the table but my lack of js knowledge caused me to simplify and this is where i got to)

thanks, kris

html

```
<div class='tabletoolkit'>
    <span class='row'>
        <span id='toolkitcell'>Excel Tips</span>
        <p id='toolkithelpbox'>tips</p>

        <span id='toolkitcell'>APS</span>
        <p id='toolkithelpbox'>access</p>
    </span>
</div>
```

css

```
.tabletoolkit
{
display:table;
border-spacing:10px;
border-collapse:separate;
text-align:center;
}

.tabletoolkit span.row a
{
display:table-row;
float:left;
text-decoration:none;
}

#toolkithelpbox
{
display:table-cell;
height:210px;
width:360px;
vertical-align:middle;
padding:5px;
background-color:yellow;
}

#toolkitcell
{
display:table-cell;
height:90px;
width:100px;
padding:5px;
vertical-align:middle;
background-color:gainsboro;
color:black;
}

#toolkitcell:hover
{
background-color:red;
color:white;
}
```

js

```
var oVTog = {
toggle: function (el) {
        oVTog.container = el.parentNode;
        oVTog.para = oVTog.container.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];  
        oVTog.para.style.display = "none";

        el.onmouseover = function () {
                      oVTog.para.style.display = '';
                      return false;
                };
        el.onmouseout = function () {
                      oVTog.para.style.display = 'none';
                      return false;
                };
        el.onclick = function () {
                      oVTog.para.style.display = oVTog.para.style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none';
                      return false;
                };
        }
};
window.onload = function () {
    var l = document.getElementById('toolkitcell');
    oVTog.toggle(l); 
};
```

Comment: When you've been using jQuery for ages its hard to read pure JavaScript :(

Comment: Multiple ids in a document is not allowed

Comment: I'm sorry to exhort but if you found my answer helpful please up-vote as useful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you correct you can do that with pure CSS and next sibling selector - [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors).

Simply hide all yellow boxes in CSS and show the next one to hovered grey box:

```
.toolkithelpbox { visibility: hidden; }
.toolkitcell:hover + .toolkithelpbox { visibility: visible; }
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/norin89/z97v25y1/)

P.S. Changed IDs to Classes cause ID must be unique and used only once.

--

**UPDATED:**
So if you want to have only one yellow box and change content inside it's still not a big deal in pure CSS :) See the [DEMO on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/norin89/z97v25y1/2/).

In this solution there's created `.placeholder` yellow box floated to right to preserve area for tips on hover. HTML structure is almost the same but in this case we position `.toolkithelpbox` absolutely to show up over the yellow box. We still use next sibling selector to show hints on grey box `:hover`:

```
.toolkithelpbox { display: none; }
.toolkitcell:hover + .toolkithelpbox { display: table; }
```

**Note:** I had to remove `display: table;` from `.tabletoolkit` because FireFox doesn't respect `position: relative;` on table elements. I needed to add additional span inside all the boxes to make `vertical-align: middle;` possible. If text in grey boxes is always going to be one line only then you can remove inner `span`s and vertically center text by setting line height to box height - `line-height: 90px;`.

Comment: thanks for helping. what i'm looking for is one yellow box that is always visible. as you hover over each grey box, a description for that grey box will appear in the one yellow box. i think my poor code has probably not helped.

Comment: Is that - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/norin89/z97v25y1/2/) - what you're aiming to achieve? If so I'll update my answer with some description. It's still pure CSS :)

Answer (score 0):

Your Goal:

> my goal is for the one yellow box to be visible on the page with
>   holding text. when you hover over the grey 'excel tips' box

HTML:

```
<div class='tabletoolkit'>
    <span class='row'>
            <span class="parent">
                <span class='toolkitcell'>Excel Tips</span>
                <p class='toolkithelpbox'>tips</p>
            </span>
            <span class="parent">
                <span class='toolkitcell'>APS</span>
                <p class='toolkithelpbox'>access</p>
            </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tabletoolkit {
    display:table;
    border-spacing:10px;
    border-collapse:separate;
    text-align:center;
}
.tabletoolkit span.row a {
    display:table-row;
    float:left;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.toolkithelpbox {
    display:table-cell;
    visibility: hidden;
    height:210px;
    width:360px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding:5px;
    background-color:yellow;
}
.toolkitcell {
    display:table-cell;
    height:90px;
    width:100px;
    padding:5px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background-color:gainsboro;
    color:black;
}
.toolkitcell:hover {
    background-color:red;
    color:white;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(".toolkitcell").hover(function () {
    $(this).siblings(".toolkithelpbox").css("visibility", "visible");

}, function () {
    $(this).siblings(".toolkithelpbox").css("visibility", "hidden");
});
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x4q381L5/5/)

Note: Ask me in comments if thats not what you want.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to help. what i'm looking for is one yellow box that will always be visible. as you hover over each grey box the description will appear in the one yellow box.

Comment: You can give data attribute to `.toolkitcell` and use it as hover text.

Comment: thanks again! sorry not exactly there, apologies for my poor guidance. there will be only one yellow box for the entire page, not for each grey box. the descriptions will all appear in the same single yellow box. that is my goal.

Comment: then what wrap them around a parent thats not anything difficult its only css